# Java Optional getter not working in modelmapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, modelmapper

Can not convert one class dto to another class dto using `ModelMapper`.

**N.B:** I don't want to use getter/setter. I want to use `Optional` getter only

Example:

```
class A {      
    Long id;

    public Optional<Long> getId() {
       return Optional.ofNullable(id);
    }
}
```

Another class:

```
class B {
    Long id;
    // getter and setter
}
```

Converter:

```
B f(A a) {
  new ModelMapper.map(a, B.class);
}
```

Error: `failed to convert java.util.Optional to java.lang.Long.\n\n1 error`

Comment: could you post more of the code and show exactly where the error occurs?

Answer (score 2):

I think that Converter can help you.

```
Converter<String, String> toUppercase = new AbstractConverter<String, String>() {
  protected String convert(String source) {
    return source == null ? null : source.toUppercase();
  }
};
```

Check it out here http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/converters/ you just need to replace one String with `Optional` and the second one with `Long`

Comment: Check link that I have attached, there is example how to attach this converter to your mapper or against your type.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that the mapper just scans fields via reflection, the build getters and expect the same return type as the field type.

That's why it can't cast `Long` to `Optional<Long>`.

As a workaround you can make the field `Optional<Long>` itself.

Or, even better, just don't return optional in POJO getters.

Comment: I want to covert domain to pojo. in domain class has optional getter.

Comment: i want to know the way of convertion using modelmapper where domain has optional getter

Answer (score 0):

Optional to object: .get()

Example:

```
   @GetMapping("/{id:[0-9]+}")
   LanguageDto getLanguageById(@PathVariable Long id) {

     Optional<Language> lang = service.findById(id);
     if (lang.isPresent()) {
        return modelMapper.map(lang.get(), LanguageDto.class);
     } else {
        throw new EntitySimpleNotFoundException("Language", id);
     } 
 }
```

-> modelMapper.map(lang.**get()**, LanguageDto.class)